# call stored function from database in pypika

Tags: pypika

I want to be able to call a stored function/procedure build with pypika like: call someprocedure(p1, p2).

The nearest I got was:
Query.from_(Function('someprocedure', p1, p2)).select("*")
resulting in:
SELECT * FROM someprocedure(1,NULL)

Replacing "SELECT * FROM" with "call"

I expect a way building the statement without replacing some text.